# India: Can an MLA/MP of a party become a minister in a government ruled by different party?

Tags: election, india

Say for example: Is it possible for Manmohan Singh to be a minister in Modi's cabinet? Or is it possible for M.K.Stalin to be a minister in Jayalalitha's cabinet? And if possible, whether any events like that happened? If not, why is it not allowed?

Comment: Unless Indian National Congress joins the Government, then no. Parties of opposition do not get to be members of cabinets unless of course extraordinary circumstances demand a national government made of all parties.

Answer (score 1):

Members from a different party being a minister in the government headed by another party happens all the time as smaller parties are given ministerial portfolios under the name of a ruling coalition. The extreme examples you have given below are also possible under the same system.  For example,  if Sasikala Pushpa who is currently out of favor with the party leadership,  wants to join the Modi government  (assuming Modi wants her), she can join the government.

There is a problem with voting with the government if her party leadership asks her to vote against the government thanks to the anti defection law of 1985.

> A member would incur a disqualification under paragraph 2 (1) (a) when he “voluntarily gives up his membership of a party” and under 2 (1) (b) when he/she votes (or abstains from voting) contrary to the directive issued by the party

Answer (score -1):

Members from a different party being a minister in the government headed by another party happens all the time as smaller parties are given ministerial portfolios under the name of a ruling coalition. The extreme examples you have given below are also possible under the same system. For example, if Sasikala Pushpa who is currently out of favor with the party leadership, wants to join the Modi government (assuming Modi wants her), she can join the government.

There is a problem with voting with the government if her party leadership asks her to vote against the government thanks to the anti defection law of 1985.